# Tomcat Crashes By throwing Fatal Error In JRE

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, openssl

I am running Tomcat 9 with `jdk 1.8.0_162-b12` on Ubuntu `16.04` 64-bit Server.
Development is done in Java.

The error in `catalina.out` shows this-

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f017456eded, pid=6838, tid=0x00007f00bb0f2700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_162-b12) (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.162-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libssl.so.1.0.0+0x25ded]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /root/hs_err_pid6838.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
```

Can anyone suggest what are the possibilities of having this error and how to resolve it?
Openssl version is 1.0.2g.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar problem, running on Debian Jessie with a libssl.so.1.0.0 from backport, Java 1.8.0_181 and Tomcat 8.5.4 running with SSL on port 8443:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff86bdd6e70, pid=16967, tid=0x00007ff7edb87700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libssl.so.1.0.0+0x40e70]  SSL_get_current_cipher+0x0
#
```

Any ideas?